# Automate posting to SharePoint with Python

Tags: sharepoint-server

I'd like to automate posting to a SharePoint news feed using Python. What is the best way I can do this? Some things I've considered:

- Using one of python's generic http modules (like requests)
- Using a python SharePoint module (if one exists)

Comment: If your client machine has .net, than you could use IronPython (Python for .NET) and use SharePoint CSOM libraries for this.

Answer (score 0):

[SharePlum](https://github.com/jasonrollins/shareplum) worked well for me with SharePoint 2007.